# Java volatile LinkedList

Tags: java, list, sorting, thread-safety

I'm trying to do a very special sorting into a LinkedList. I use a ListIterator to find the place where I want to add an item and that works quiet well. Only problem is that I have multiple threads that want to add and sort items. The adding itself is synchronized but a LinkedList uses non volatile properties. That isn't safe, is it? Here is what I'm trying to do (simplified):

```
public class Test {
    private LinkedList<Long> list = new LinkedList<Long>();

    synchronized void add ( final long number ) {
        // iterate our sorting list
        final ListIterator<Long> iterator = list.listIterator( list.size() );
        while (iterator.hasPrevious()) {
            long current = iterator.previous();
            if (current < number) {
                if (iteratot.nextIndex() >= list.size()) {
                    list.add( number ); // I don't need the iterator anymore
                } else {
                    iterator.next();
                    iterator.add( number );
                }
            }
            // This here gets difficult 
            // I need the current number here! (which is the one that is a little lower than the added one)
        }
    }
}
```

The source above only resembles what I'm doing and is much more simple that the original.

Is there another List type I haven't seen which is thread safe or another solution which I just don't know about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as the only way to access and modify `Test.list` is through `Test.add()`, your code is thread safe.

If there are other ways to access/modify `Test.list`, you need to tell us more.

Comment: The only thought I had was because the properties of the LinkedList aren't volatile. This is no problem then?

Comment: if you are using synchronized it establishes happens-before relationship and so it is thread safe IMO

Answer (score 0):

You can see the [synchronizedList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList%28java.util.List%29) method.

> Returns a synchronized (thread-safe) list backed by the specified list. In order to guarantee serial access, it is critical that all access to the backing list is accomplished through the returned list.

Comment: The only thing a synchronizedList does is synchronize the access which  I'm doing too with my method so it would be pointless.